# Cannot Use DbContext.Query inside a transaction

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2015

I am using EF6 to query a backend database. User can customize a temporary table and query the data from the temporary table. I am using

`DataTable result = context.Query(queryStatement);`

to get the result and it has been working fine.

Now the query is needed among a serious of other sqlcommand and a transaction is needed. So I have

```
public static DataTable GetData()
{
    using (MyDbContext context = new MyDbContext())
    using (DbContextTransaction tran = context.Database.BeginTransaction())
    {
        try
        {
            int rowAffected = context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(
                "UPDATE [MyDb].dbo.[TableLocks] SET RefCount = RefCount + 1 WHERE TableName = 'TESTTABLE1'");
            if (rowAffected != 1)
                throw new Exception("Cannot find 'TestTable1'");

            //The following line will raise an exception
            DataTable result = context.Query("SELECT TOP 100 * FROM [MyDb].dbo.[TestTable1]");
            //This line will work if I change it to 
            //context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("SELECT TOP 100 * FROM [MyDb].dbo.[TestTable1]");
            //but I don't know how to get the result out of it.
            context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(
                "UPDATE [MyDb].dbo.[TableLocks] SET RefCount = RefCount - 1 WHERE TableName = 'TestTable1'");
            tran.Commit();

            return result;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            tran.Rollback();
            throw (ex);
        }
    }
}
```

But this throws an exception while executing context.Query

```
ExecuteReader requires the command to have a transaction when the connection 
assigned to the command is in a pending local transaction.  The Transaction 
property of the command has not been initialized.
```

And when I read this article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/saving/transactions
It says:

> Entity Framework does not wrap queries in a transaction.

Is it the reason cause this issue?

How can I use `context.Query()` inside a transaction?

What else I can use?

I tried all other method, none of them work - because the return datatype cannot be predicted before hand.

I just realized that, the Query method is defined in MyDbContext!

```
    public DataTable Query(string sqlQuery)
    {
        DbProviderFactory dbFactory = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory(Database.Connection);

        using (var cmd = dbFactory.CreateCommand())
        {
            cmd.Connection = Database.Connection;
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.CommandText = sqlQuery;
            using (DbDataAdapter adapter = dbFactory.CreateDataAdapter())
            {
                adapter.SelectCommand = cmd;

                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                adapter.Fill(dt);

                return dt;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: IDE: Visual Studio 2015. ASP.Net Core: 1.0

Comment: I have attached the minimum code that can reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry guys, as mentioned above, I thought the Query method is from EF, but I examined the code and found **it is actually coded by another developer, defined in class MyDbContext.** Since this class is generated by EF, and I never think somebody have added a method.

It is

```
public DataTable Query(string sqlQuery)
{
    DbProviderFactory dbFactory = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory(Database.Connection);

    using (var cmd = dbFactory.CreateCommand())
    {
        cmd.Connection = Database.Connection;
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.CommandText = sqlQuery;

        //And I added this line, then problem solved.
        if (Database.CurrentTransaction != null)
            cmd.Transaction = Database.CurrentTransaction.UnderlyingTransaction;

        using (DbDataAdapter adapter = dbFactory.CreateDataAdapter())
        {
            adapter.SelectCommand = cmd;

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            adapter.Fill(dt);

            return dt;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

May be you are missing this section -

> you are free to execute database operations either directly on the
>   SqlConnection itself, or on the DbContext. All such operations are
>   executed within one transaction. You take responsibility for
>   committing or rolling back the transaction and for calling Dispose()
>   on it, as well as for closing and disposing the database connection

And then this codebase -

```
using (var conn = new SqlConnection("..."))
{
    conn.Open();

    using (var sqlTxn = 
    conn.BeginTransaction(System.Data.IsolationLevel.Snapshot))
    {
        try
        {
            var sqlCommand = new SqlCommand();
            sqlCommand.Connection = conn;
            sqlCommand.Transaction = sqlTxn;
            sqlCommand.CommandText =
                       @"UPDATE Blogs SET Rating = 5" +
                        " WHERE Name LIKE '%Entity Framework%'";
            sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

            using (var context =  
                new BloggingContext(conn, contextOwnsConnection: false))
            {
                        context.Database.UseTransaction(sqlTxn);

                        var query =  context.Posts.Where(p => p.Blog.Rating >= 5);
                        foreach (var post in query)
                        {
                            post.Title += "[Cool Blog]";
                        }
                       context.SaveChanges();
                    }

                    sqlTxn.Commit();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
             sqlTxn.Rollback();
        }
    }
}
```

Specially this one -

```
context.Database.UseTransaction(sqlTxn);
```

Comment: This example demonstrate how to use outside transaction for DbContext. I am not using outside transaction, but using the one from internal (tran = context.Database.BeginTranasction(). So it make no sense to UseTransaction( a transaction that was created by my self)

Comment: I got a feeling that, context.Query is not in scope of context.Database's transaction, but I don't know how to specify the same transaction to context level.....  The worst case, I may try to create a transaction outside and, do NOT use dbContext.Database.BeginTransaction(), use dbContext.Database.UseTransaction(OutsideTran) instead and see if it will work or not.

Comment: tried, no luck. it seems even i set the transaction externally, the dbcontext can always get arround of it, and it seems that function cannot be execute inside any transaction.... weird...

Comment: Instead of removing some lines, could you update the question with the actual code. I have a feeling something else is not right.

Comment: However, there is one thing to notice, you are kind of mixing codes from both world , raw SQL queries and ORM. It usually is a bad design. Either don't use EF and use ADO.net or use EF and use it with a POCO.

Comment: I am using EF everywhere else, but in order to query an unknown table, EF cannot archive it. i have to use Query() directly.